# Sharepoint portal, jQuery Ajax post data are null after request.getParameterValues()

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, servlets, portal

I have an Ajax call, it's working well in my application. but if I use it on Sharepoint portal, it's value is null. I have been searching online for one day.

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',

                    url: url,

                    dataType : 'json',

                    data : {"docids":["doc_name1","doc_name2","doc_name3"]} })
```

In HttpServletRequest `String[] aDocIds = aRequest.getParameterValues("docids");`

The aDocIds is null.

I tried this to get the data value but with no luck.

```
if (aDocIds == null)
  {
    StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    try
    {
      BufferedReader reader = aRequest.getReader();
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        jb.append(line);

    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(jb.toString());

    // here the jsonObject is null, jb 
    JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("arrayParamName");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { /*report an error*/
    }
  }
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: To read json on the server you have to send json on the client, which you're not doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
data : {"docids":["doc_name1","doc_name2","doc_name3"]}
```

Comment: Hi Musa, thank you for your post. I made a mistake to my post, my data is: data : {"docids":["doc_name1",doc_name2","doc_name3"]}, it's working fine with my application, but in sharepoint portal it's null.

Comment: @BillChan try `data : "docids=doc_name1&docids=doc_name2&docids=doc_name3"`